# jquery , validator invalid class being applied to non-empty fields on submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form where i am using jquery and validate. 
I am using errorPlacement in the validate to put a border around required fields that are missing.
it seems to work as i would like except when the fields are pre-filled.
When the form is submitted, The validate marks the pre-filled text fields are invalid. 
if I give focus and then leave the field the pre-filled fields will all remove the borders.
See example at http://jsfiddle.net/paries/u3Td3/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your CSS to hang off of `.error`, which is the class jQuery validate uses by default to indicate invalid fields.

Your problem is happening because of order: your `:not('.valid')` check gets run *before* the valid classes have been added. If you inspect your prepopulated inputs after clicking "continue" in your example, you'll find that they have both `invalid` and `valid` as classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/u3Td3/12/

Answer (score 1):

you can check for an error text before placement.

```
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(error.text().length>0){
            $(element).filter(':not(.valid)').addClass("invalid");
        }
    },
```